# XSS issues for html controls and request parameters

Tags: json, xss, antisamy

I need to fix XSS issues in my application. Now I am new to JSON and XSS. I think of two ways attacks can happen - first is through html input controls (text boxe/area etc) or through request parameters which are visible in the url (GET). Please suggest if i am missing something here?

I am thinking to use AntiSamy (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project). I am thinking of creating a custom tag which would contain the value of html controls e.g.

<input type="text" NAME="name" value="<mytag:xssclean><c:out value= escapeXml="false"/></mytag:xssclean>

this tag class would actually use antisamy to scan the html content. will this take care of encoding any malicious javascript content entered into text box/area before sending those parameters to controller classes and then eventually to database? Or would it only encode the content which is coming from controller classes to get rendered on jsp?

Is this the right approach? When would i need to validate on the java side (controller classes by direct validation using antisamy) versus on jsp (with new tag)?

Additionally I have many jsp's which do not have direct form fields with html controls but their struture is created dynamically and jason string is given to the jsp. jsp would simply have :     where 'value' would contain the final jason to be rendered on html (including html fields). Do we need to apply XSS solution using antisamy on jason strings or jason data is already safe from XSS attacks and the thing like  are already present as text in jason? where should i resolve this issue for json cases?

Comment: can someone please provide inputs